# Removing first line From selection VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I've got a set of data, that's been autofiltered down to meet certain criteria. This subset of the data I want to paste into a new sheet, so it's by itself, and then remove it from the main sheet.

I've got most of this down, except for the last part, removing it from the main sheet. The main problem is that I need to keep the header line of the main sheet, and since these results are auto-filtered, i can't count on the second line being 2. I've tried a number of different things, the latest being offsetting to the second line after I copied what I need to the second sheet. Here's what I have so far (and yes, some things are commented out for testing, I don't need to be using precious seconds doing something I know works)

```
Sub copyToN2r()
'
' copyton2r Macro
'
'
Dim Lr As Long
Dim start As Long

Lr = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
'Range("A" & Lr).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy
Destination:=Sheets("N2R Register").Range("A1")
'Range("A1:F1").Copy
Range("A1").Offset(1, 0).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Clear
'Range("A1").Paste
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See if the snippet below will work for you -- comments inline:

```
Sub copyToNewSheet()

    ' data that will be copied
    Dim dataWithHeader As Range
    Dim dataOnly As Range

    Set dataWithHeader = [Sheet3!a1].CurrentRegion
    With dataWithHeader
        Set dataOnly = .Offset(1, 0).Resize(.Rows.Count - 1, .Columns.Count)
    End With

    ' so now you copy data and the header
    dataWithHeader.Copy [Sheet4!a1]

    ' and delete copied visible rows
    ' you can't iterate throw rows and delete those rows at the same time
    ' as it will cause issues. We first need to store all the ranges we'll delete
    ' in a collection -- and then iterate through that collection
    Dim rw As Range
    Dim cRowsToDel As New Collection
    For Each rw In dataOnly.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Rows
        cRowsToDel.Add rw
    Next
    For Each rw In cRowsToDel
        rw.Delete xlShiftUp
    Next

    ' remove autofilter to see the results
    If [Sheet3].AutoFilterMode Then [Sheet3].ShowAllData
End Sub
```

Test data set with column headers and rows 2 and 3 filtered out (paste in A1):

```
col1    col2    col3
data11  data21  data31
data12  data22  data32
data13  data23  data33
data14  data24  data34
data15  data25  data35
```

Comment: Hey Logan, Thanks for this, it works in its own workbook, with your test data. However, when I moved it to my book, and changed the sheet references,  I get a "copy Method of Range class failed error 1004. Any idea on cause?

Comment: @David It is very likely that `[Sheet3!a1].CurrentRegion` doesn't find the data table properly. Try specifying the range explicitly and see if it works -- for example `[Sheet3!a1:f40]`

Comment: Logan, thanks again, it was actually the sheet4 line that was giving me problems, but i changed the name of the actual sheet to Sheet2 instead and it's working fine now. THanks for the help!